# sqlite jquery java query

Tags: javascript

I have a java sql query I need to convert to c# query is there any convert for that or anyone knows how to convert it

java query
followed by a variable/property/constant called id. Variables have a value which is typically not the variable name. So you will have to insert the value of variable TRAINEEID instead of the variable name.

Comment: `"SELECT " + TRAINING_PLAN_TRAINEEID + ", count(*)  from "` tells you that there is the text "SELECT " followed by a variable/property/constant called TRAINING_PAN_TRAINEEID. Variables have a value which is typically not the variable name. So you will have to insert the value of variable TRAINING_PLAN_TRAINEEID instead of the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            string countQuery = @"SELECT TRAINING_PLAN_TRAINEEID, count(*)  from TABLE_TRAINING_PLAN  WHERE 
                     TRAINING_PLAN_TRAINEEID IN (SELECT 
                    GRP_EMPLOYEE_USERID  FROM  TABLE_GRP_EMPLOYEE WHERE  GRP_EMPLOYEE_SITEID  =@siteId and 
                    GRP_EMPLOYEE_ISACTIVE =1) and 
                     TRAINING_PLAN_STATUS =2 and
  TRAINING_PLAN_ISACTIVE  =1 group by 
                    TRAINING_PLAN_TRAINEEID;"
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(countQuery, conn))
       {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteId", whereArgs[0]);
         using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             // process the results
         }
       }
```

Comment: not working sir

Comment: did you add the @siteId parameter?
what error you got?

Comment: TRAINING_PLAN_TRAINEEID doese not exits

Comment: not working sir

Comment: please add the full code so we can check where the problem is.